# Text element in SVG positions itself perfectly inspite of fixed values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I was going through the source code of circliful.js and I came across the following lines of code:

```
'<text class="timer" text-anchor="middle" x="' + textX + '" y="' + textY 
                        + '" style="font-size: ' + settings.percentageTextSize + 'px; ' + additionalCss + ';' 
                        + settings.textAdditionalCss + '" fill="' + settings.fontColor + '">0%</text>'
```

Given that the value of textX and textY are a constant `175` and `35` respectively, how is it that when the width of the circle changes, the position of the icon remains the same?

Basically the line of code above is the percent value you see in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/40hzvugz/), the `50%` you see in the fiddle is the above line of code.

So when I have the below CSS:

```
#circli {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

The placement of the 50% is still at the same place in spite of the constant values of `175` and `35`, also if I change the CSS like so:

```
#circli {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

The position of the `50%` is still the same in spite of having a constant value of `175` and `35`. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

The elements in the SVG are defined in a constant coordinate system.  All you are doing is changing the size of the `<div>` that the SVG is inside.  The SVG is automatically scaling to fit the div.

The SVG is scaling because it has a `viewBox`.  The viewBox tells the renderer what the limits of the SVG document are, and triggers the automatic scaling.  If it didn't have a viewBox, it wouldn't be automatically resized.